# Receive deprecation warning error when testing code via herku local, but receive no error with Node.js interpreter

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my react app to heroku, but when using `heroku local` I recieve an error regarding moment.js:

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3ppD.png)

So heroku raises an error, but the Node.js interpreter doesn't.

Is there a way to circumvent this error?

Comment: I'm betting it's a versioning issue, can you post what version of moment and node you're running on your dev box vice those that are in the heroku local container?

Comment: Node: v6.4.0 and moment: 2.17.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecation message is just a warning, it's not an error. It seems like the error is in your code, probably you are using `moment` constructor with a non-ISO string then moment calls `createFromInputFallback` and it tries to construct a new `Date` with your input `new Date('your date')` but it fails and throws an error.